# Smallest singular value is the reciprocal of the largest singular value?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, singular-values

Under what conditions does this hold? In particular, I'm interested in square invertible matrices that satisfy this condition.

Note that in this case, the condition number of the matrix equals the square of the largest singular value. I stumbled upon such a matrix doing some experiments and became curious what is known about this property.

Comment: It is true **iff** $\|A^{-1}\| = \|A\|$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Using which norm?

Comment: @celtschk Spectral norm, AKA induced 2-norm

Comment: For any matrix $A$, $\sqrt{\kappa(A)}\cdot A$ will have this property, where $\kappa(A)$ is the condition number of $A$.